# Add a Weekly Column average automatically after 7 Days

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Currently my sheet]

I currently have a formula in Cell B1 which is pulling all the unique dates within my dataset and sort them from recent to oldest. What I would like to do is, after every 7th date to automatically create a column with "Weekly Average" and then continue the dates within the data set once again.

Example:

[image: Example]

I am not sure if this is possible via a formula, or if I would need to script something to get the same result, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be possible with a formula in theory, but I'm wondering if there will be some dates missing in practice which would mean you couldn't just insert a new heading every seven columns because the dates wouldn't match with Monday-Sunday any more?

Comment: Hi @TomSharpe

Thanks for the reply, Only date that will be missing when it comes around will be Christmas Day + Easter Friday. Other then that, there should be data every single day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept for February - not quite there yet because it should display a final total for 28th February.

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(filter(flatten(split(sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false)&if(WEEKDAY(sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false))=2,"\Weekly average",),"\"))
,flatten(split(sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false)&if(WEEKDAY(sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false))=2,"\Weekly average",),"\"))<>"")))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(filter(flatten(split(if(WEEKDAY(sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false))=1,"Weekly average\",)
&sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false),"\"))
,flatten(split(if(WEEKDAY(sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false))=1,"Weekly average\",)
&sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false),"\"))<>"")))
```

[image]

It would be shorter to use query than filter:

```
=ArrayFormula(text(transpose(query(flatten(""&split(if(WEEKDAY(sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false))=1,"Weekly average\",)
&sort(unique(filter(datevalue('Cleaned Data'!A2:A),'Cleaned Data'!A2:A<>"")),1,false),"\"))
,"select  Col1 where Col1 is not null")),"DD/MM/YYYY"))
```

These should be OK up to Christmas 2022, which falls on a Sunday.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tom Sharpe. Works perfectly :)